# Error: no suitable conversion function from "std::string" to "char *" exists

Tags: visual-c++

basically I'm trying to secure some of the strings from my source but I keep getting this error on this line:

```
playerOptionsMenu->SetMenuTitle(base64_encode(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(playeroptionstitle.c_str()), playeroptionstitle.length()));
```

The error occurs on the *base64_encode*

Here is the definition of playeroptionstitle:

```
const std::string playeroptionstitle = "Player Options";
```

Here is the header for the base64_encode:

```
std::string base64_encode(unsigned char const* , unsigned int len);
```

The error I am getting is: *Error: no suitable conversion function from "std::string" to "char *" exists*

Comment: You can use the method `c_str` to get a `const char *`

Comment: What is the signature of `SetMenuTitle`? If it is `char *`, then this is the issue and you need to add another `.c_str()` after the closing `)` for the call to `base64_encode`.